# How to Troubleshoot slow DB2OLEDB Connection

Tags: c#, performance, iis, db2, oledbconnection

I am attempting to connect to a DB2 database using DB2OLEDB provider. On the development machine, the connection opens in 1 second on average.  On the test machine, the connection is taking 20 seconds.  This is strictly opening the connection; no SQL command is being issued.  What are possible factors I need to look at?

The development machine is physical while the test server is a VM.
Both have 16GB ram.
The connection request is within a C# ASP.Net application hosted in IIS.
The network team has confirmed that the lag time is occurring when the connection request is made to the DB2 database.
I have hosted the app locally using IIS Express and the performance is fine.

```
 public bool IsServiceAvailable()
        {
            try
            {
                using (var conn = GetCisDBConnection())
                {
                    conn.Open();  // <-- 20 second lag
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        private OleDbConnection GetCisDBConnection()
        {
            var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CIS_OleDB"].ConnectionString;
            return new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
        }
```

Comment: Network delay? Authentication delay? Authentication setup?  Differences in the provisioning for the different Db2-server resources? Database is activated already?   You need to dig deeper.

Comment: Eventually I wound up using the DB2Client instead of DB2OLEDB.  To address your questions though: